# Dropdown list not slide toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot seem to understand why in the world my slide toggle is not working. could someone tell me what I'm missing? and then please explain to me what I was doing wrong? I have not done web dev in over 2 years, but this all looks solid to me, not sure what I'm missing.

```js
$(document).ready(
function listItemsSmooth(){
    $('.main-ul').children('.li').on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
   });
   $("#newFunction").click(listItemsSmooth);
});
```

```css
.main-li-items{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
/*.main-li-items:hover .sub-li-items{
  display:block;
}*/
.sub-li-items{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40.5px;
    display: none
}
ul{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<nav>
    <nav class = "home-main-nav-menu">
    <ul class = "main-ul" id ="newFunction">
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Home</a></li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">About Me</a>
        <ul>
          <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Education</a></li>
          <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Blog</a></li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Email</a></li>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Phone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Recent</a></li>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">All</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Collaborate</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Now</li>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Later</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Comment: Make sure to include jQuery version in your code snippet. I see a console error rrunning your code and i think that's the reason. When I try to run the code I see `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`

Comment: I just pasted it in the html portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things contributing to this! The first is that your script is looking for a child element of class `.li` when it should be looking for the element `li`

Additionally, the CSS is hiding the `<li>` elements, not the `<ul>` which is the element being side-toggled.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.main-ul').children('li').on('click', function() {
     $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

```css
.main-li-items{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
.main-li-items > ul {
  display: none;
}
/*.main-li-items:hover .sub-li-items{
  display:block;
}*/
.sub-li-items{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40.5px;
}
ul{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <nav class = "home-main-nav-menu">
    <ul class = "main-ul" id = "newFunction">
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Home</a></li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">About Me</a>
        <ul>
          <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Education</a></li>
          <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Blog</a></li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Contact</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Email</a></li>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Phone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Portfolio</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Recent</a></li>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">All</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Collaborate</a>
      <ul>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Now</a></li>
        <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Later</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct so many things so just compare your code and my code :

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjk2y5oy/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 function listItemsSmooth(){
            $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('slow');
  }
 $(".main-li-items").click(listItemsSmooth);
});
```

```css
.main-li-items{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 21px;
}
.main-li-items > ul{
  display: none;
}
.sub-li-items{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -40.5px;
}
ul{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <nav class = "home-main-nav-menu">
    <ul class = "main-ul" id ="newFunction">
      
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Home</a></li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">About Me</a>
       
       <ul>
          <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Education</a></li>
          <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
        
      </li>
      
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Blog</a></li>
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Contact</a>
        
          <ul>
            <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Email</a></li>
            <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Phone</a></li>
          </ul>
        
      </li>
      
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#/">Portfolio</a>
         
         <ul>
            <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">Recent</a></li>
            <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#/">All</a></li>
          </ul>
          
       </li>
       
      <li class = "main-li-items"><a href = "#">Collaborate</a>
         
         <ul>
            <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#"/>Now</li>
            <li class = "sub-li-items"><a href = "#"/>Later</li>
          </ul>
          
      </li>
      
    </ul>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

Comment: It would be better if you give enough explanation of you answer.